# d3js rectangle strip gauge chart

Tags: d3.js

[image]

How would I convert the current code to something like this pressure chart - where rectangles are arranged in an arc -- and then the best case tick is highlighted to represent the value.

So we would append rectangles and change the angle as we create the skeleton.

I've got this demo that creates a spread of rectangles and changes the angles - but I am not sure how to stabilize this and create the arc from the left side - https://jsfiddle.net/smo6kqzw/3/

```
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr("height", 500).attr("width", 500).attr("class", "svger")




var rectbuf = 50;

var padd = 1;

  
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

svg.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 30)
  .attr("height", 20)
  .attr("fill", "red")
  .attr("y", 20)
  .attr("x", rectbuf * 5)
  .attr("transform", "rotate("+((5+padd) *i)+")")

}
```

---

```
// create svg element:
var svg = d3.select("#rect").append("svg").attr("width", 800).attr("height", 200)

// Add the path using this helper function
svg.append('rect')
  .attr('x', 10)
  .attr('y', 120)
  .attr('width', 600)
  .attr('height', 40)
  .attr('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('fill', '#69a3b2');
```

I currently have a dial chart that looks like this
[image]

```
import React from 'react'
import * as d3 from 'd3'

class GaugeChart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.myRef = React.createRef()
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      theme: this.props.theme
        ? this.props.theme
        : ['#bde0fe', '#2698f9', '#71bcfd', '#f1f8fe'],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var $this = this.myRef.current

    d3.select($this).selectAll('svg').remove()

    const value = this.props.value
    const data = [
      {
        label: 'Completed',
        value: value,
      },
      {
        label: 'Remaining',
        value: 100 - value,
      },
    ]

    const width = parseInt(this.props.width, 10),
      height = parseInt(this.props.height, 10),
      radius = parseInt(this.props.r, 10),
      innerradius = parseInt(this.props.ir, 10)

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(this.state.theme)

    var arc = d3.arc().outerRadius(radius).innerRadius(innerradius)

    data.forEach(function (d) {
      d.total = +d.value
    })

    var pie = d3
      .pie()
      .startAngle(-90 * (Math.PI / 180))
      .endAngle(90 * (Math.PI / 180))
      .padAngle(0.02) // some space between slices
      .sort(null)
      .value(function (d) {
        return d.total
      })

    var svg = d3
      .select($this)
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height + 5)
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'piechart')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height + ')')

    var segments = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'segments')

    var slices = segments
      .selectAll('.arc')
      .data(pie(data))
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'arc')

    slices
      .append('path')
      .attr('d', arc)
      .attr('fill', function (d, i) {
        return color(i)
      })
    /*.transition()
          .attrTween('d', function(d) {
            var i = d3.interpolate(d.startAngle + 0.1, d.endAngle);
            return function(t) {
              d.endAngle = i(t);
              return arc(d);
            }
          } )*/

    var arrow = svg.append('g').attr('transform', 'rotate( 0  )')

    arrow
      .append('path')
      .attr('fill', '#ef7e60')
      .attr(
        'd',
        `M -${innerradius - 5},0 -${innerradius - 12},-5 -${
          innerradius - 12
        },5`,
      ) // draw triangle

    var text = svg
      .append('text')
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .attr('dy', 0)
      .attr('fill', '#ef7e60')

    function update(data) {
      text.text(`${Math.round(data[0].value)}%`) // set % text

      arrow.transition().attr('transform', `rotate( ${data[0].value * 1.8}  )`) //rotate to desired qantity ( i put to 60% of 180 deg )
    }
    update(data)
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} className="GaugeChart" />
  }
}
export default GaugeChart
```

--
latest fiddle 2nd Dec
https://jsfiddle.net/gp4wL80t/

latest fiddle 3rd Dec
https://jsfiddle.net/0k7zvdxn/

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff - any suggestions on how to start making this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your demo code re...

> "I've got this demo that creates a spread of rectangles and changes
> the angles - but I am not sure how to stabilize this and create the
> arc from the left side"

Really you just need to modify the starting angle then calculate the positions for the ticks directly along the arc.

**EDIT**

You can make the bars thicker by using `stroke-width`, go around the edges more by adjusting the `startAngle` and `endAngle` (in radians).

To highlight the nearest marker that would approximate the value, and also display the value in the middle/bottom like the pressure example - you just need to calculate the marker based on the value and display the text, etc - e.g.

```js
const value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100); // value you want to show, random here just as an example...
const numTicks = 50; // total ticks around the edge
const lineThickness = 3; // width of ticks 
const tickLength = 10; // length of ticks 
const arcRadius = 55; // size of the arc
const startAngle = -220 * (Math.PI / 180); // first tick pos in rad
const endAngle = 40 * (Math.PI / 180); // last tick pos in rad
const centerX = 75;
const centerY = 75;
const width = 150;
const height = 150;

const svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("class", "svger");

for (let i = 0; i < numTicks; i++) {
  const angle = startAngle + (i / (numTicks - 1)) * (endAngle - startAngle);
  const isHighlighted = i === Math.round((value / 100) * (numTicks - 1));
  const highlightAmmount = isHighlighted ? 2 : 0; // highlight sizing
  const x1 = centerX + arcRadius * Math.cos(angle);
  const y1 = centerY + arcRadius * Math.sin(angle);
  const x2 = x1 + (tickLength + highlightAmmount) * Math.cos(angle);
  const y2 = y1 + (tickLength + highlightAmmount) * Math.sin(angle);
  const tick = svg.append("line")
    .attr("x1", x1)
    .attr("y1", y1)
    .attr("x2", x2)
    .attr("y2", y2)
    .attr("stroke", isHighlighted ? "#ffffff" : '#6294d5') // highlight colour
    .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
    .attr("stroke-width", lineThickness + highlightAmmount);
}

svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", centerX)
  .attr("y", centerY)
  .text(value)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
  .attr("font-family", "Arial")
  .attr("font-size", "30px")
  .attr("font-weight", "bold")
  .attr("fill", "#ffffff");

svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", 35)
  .attr("y", height - 15)
  .text("Low")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
  .attr("font-family", "Arial")
  .attr("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("fill", "#ffffff");

svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", width - 35)
  .attr("y", height - 15)
  .text("High")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
  .attr("font-family", "Arial")
  .attr("font-size", "12px")
  .attr("fill", "#ffffff");
```

```css
.svger {
  background: #4c7dbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I also styled it to look more like your example. Note the value I've displayed is random just to show how the highlighting is working. i.e. each time you click `run code snippet` a different value is shown :)

I also made a fiddle if you want to play with it - https://jsfiddle.net/fraser/9nyc5eb1/

Comment: This is good - how could you make the bars thicker, go around the edges more - also highlight the nearest marker that would approximate the value --and also display the value in the middle/bottom like the pressure example

Comment: @TheOldCounty sure, see my edit...

Comment: @TheOldCounty obviously you can alter the  `numTicks`, `tickLength`, `arcRadius` , etc  however you want.

Comment: what about the low/high labels - and the slightly faded arc that comes with the highlighted tick

Comment: @TheOldCounty  You would just add text in the same way as I have added the value text, i.e. add svg text elements, position them and style them. To do the faded arc you could just use a filter to add a glow to the highlighted tick. If you want me to create this for you in its entirety I offer reasonable freelance rates. The question wasn't can you perfectly recreate this image in d3 - it was "I am not sure how to stabilize this and create the arc from the left side"

Comment: That is true - but that comment is where I got up that had held me back on replication - one issue with the labels is ensuring they map on change of the size of the chart etc..

Comment: @TheOldCounty - then just make them proportional to centerX , centerY, or width, height, etc. See my edit